# Objective-C repeatable random number generators a la java.util.Random

Tags: objective-c, random

For testing and other purposes, it is often useful to be able to generate multiple streams of repeatable random numbers.  In Java, there is java.util.Random.  You can create multiple Random objects each with their own seed so that subsequent calls to any particular Random instance will return the same sequence of pseudo random numbers every time you run the program.  I've seen the documentation for arc4random, which looks like a great generator.  However, I don't see any way to provide a seed or anyway to support multiple independent instances.  It looks like the random() family of BSD library functions is the best way to do this. Something like the following excerpt...

```
@interface Random : NSObject {
    @private
    char _state[256];
}

+ (Random *)getDefaultInstance;
+ (Random *)getRepeatableInstance;
- (Random *)init;
- (Random *)initWithSeed:(unsigned)seed;
- (long)nextLong;
@end

@implementation Random

- (void)setup:(unsigned)seed
{
    initstate(seed, _state, sizeof(_state));
}

- (Random *)init
{
    self = [super init];
    unsigned seed = (unsigned)arc4random();
    [self setup:seed];
    return self;
}

- (Random *)initWithSeed:(unsigned int)seed
{
    self = [super init];
    [self setup:seed];
    return self;
}

- (long)nextLong
{
    char *oldState = setstate(_state);
    long result = random();
    setstate(oldState);
    return result;
}
@end
```

Is there already something else that does this?  I'm not concerned about thread safety.  I won't use generators across threads.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there already something else that does this?"

It's always difficult to answer with "no" since it's difficult to argue that I know everything because I certainly don't, but no -- I've never encountered anything like that (as an Cocoa class, that is. The usecase itself is common enough).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called pseudo-random number generation.
Some algorithms here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29494/pseudo-random-number-generation-algorithms or more info here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generators.

Using system functions (`rand()`, `srand()`, `random()`, `srandom()` and `arc4random()`) is generally enough for everybody's needs.

Also note that `long` in obj-c is very different from `long` in Java.

Comment: I'm not sure if you read my question completely.  I know about those system functions.  My solution, which uses the random() family, works for me but I'd rather use something provided as a standard component.  I don't just need pseudo-random numbers but I need multiple repeatable streams of them.  So for instance I might want thread A on machine 1 to see the same sequence of numbers as thread A on machine 2.  Similarly, I want thread B on machine 1 to see the same sequence as thread B on machine 2.  This requires 2 objects, each seeded independently that I can switch back and forth between.

Comment: Also, a primitive long in Java is nearly the same things as a long in Objective-C (64 bit primitive integer).  Perhaps you are referring to java.lang.Long objects, which are boxed numbers as in NSNumber.

Comment: @Chuck Sorry, my eyes skipped one part of the question... Anyway - note that in most of the functions the last random number works as the seed for the new one, so it's very easy to implement independent instances - just remember the last number and use it for srand() before rand().

Comment: @Chuck That's the problem. `long` in Obj-C is not a 64 bit integer. It can be, but on most machines it is just a synonym for `int` and you'll have to use `long long` to get 64 bits. On a 32 bit mac or iOS it will be only 32bits long.

Comment: Very good point about long long.  I've fixed my typedef and added unit tests to verify my typedef size assumptions.